# How to find duplicated characters

Tags: java, character

My program returns the wrong answer, that is 0, so how can I fix it? It was written in Java. Duplicated characters in the string question. It must be "u" and "e", could you please help me fix this?

```
package sude;

public class deneme {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(trial("suuudeeeee"));

    }

    public static String trial(String a) {
        for (int i=0; i<=a.length(); i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<=a.length();) {
                if(a.charAt(i)==a.charAt(j)) {
                    return Integer.toString(j);
                }
                else {
                    return "There is no duplicate";
                }
    
            }

        }
        return a;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code line-by-line and you will see why it doesn't do what you want it to do. The truth is out there.

Answer (score 0):

First off your loops need to drop the <= and just use <.  If 'i' or 'j' is == to a.length() you are out of bounds.

Second, your not iterating 'j'.  You need to add j++ to the 'j' for loop.

Third, if you both start 'i' and 'j' at zero, all characters will match to themselves.  You'll want to start 'j' after 'i' for every 'i' loop.

Fourth, you cannot return a single value and expect two results: 'u' and 'e'.
Unless you return a Collection ( or return the string value of a Collection ).

You should add some prints to the loop to debug what's actually happening.  The print outs can be removed once you understand the loop.

Final note, a little white space goes along way for readability.

```
public static String trial( String a ) {
    Set<Character> dups = new HashSet<>();

    for ( int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++ ) {
    
        for( int j = i + 1; j < a.length(); j++ ) {

            System.out.println( "i: " + i + " / " + a.charAt( i ) + "; j: " + j + " / " + a.charAt( j ) );

            if( a.charAt( i ) == a.charAt( j ) )
                dups.add( a.charAt( i ) );

        }

    }
    return dups.toString();
}
```